# Regex to Match Repetitive Digits

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex to match a phone number **only if it ends with 3 similar numbers.** Like `550268000`.

```
^5(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1|\2)(\d)(?!\1|\2|\3)(\d)(?!\1|\2|\4)(\d)(\d)\6{2}$
```

The problem with my regex is that it won't match the phone number if it has another number that is randomly repeated 3 times in different indexes. Like `550568000`.

I want my regex to match the digit if it ends with three similar numbers despite having random repetition of another digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^5\d*(\d)\1{2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C7aus8/2)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `5`: Match digit `5`
- `\d*`: Match 0 or more digits
- `(\d)`: Match a digit and capture in group #1
- `\1{2}`: Match 2 repetitions of captured value in group #1
- `$`: End

Comment: Regex101.com is a total lifesaver when it comes to regex!